# Is it feasible to send tcp package to a given IP address in C++?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, ipv4

I have already made a simple tcp server. Here is the important part of it:

```
for (;;)
    {

        char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = "";

        sockaddr_in their_add;

        socklen_t size = sizeof(their_add);
        int connection = accept(m_Socket, (sockaddr *)&their_add, &size);

        val_read = read(connection, buffer, 1024);

        std::cout << "Received: " << buffer << "\n";

        std::cout << "Number of bytes read: " << val_read << "\n";

        std::cout << "Ip address: " << inet_ntoa(their_add.sin_addr) << "\n";

        std::string content = buffer;
        const std::string ip_address = inet_ntoa(their_add.sin_addr);
```

Also I have:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> ip_address;
```

The question is, can I send data somehow from the server to a tcp client just by having the client's ip address?

I'm quite new to this.

Comment: It is not a client that's "listening" to a server, in the most common meaning of these terms. Your question is unclear.

Comment: I made a bit of change, I hope it became clearer.

Comment: @james23 The whole difference between "server" and "client" is that a client may initiate a connection with the server, while the server only waits for a client to do so. You are basically asking whether the server is also a client and the client is also a server. Of course you can design your application that way, but you can't connect to another machine if there isn't anything listening for a connection on there.

Comment: @user17732522 So there is no way for the server to start a connection to the client?

Comment: @james23 No, because then it would be the client and the other side would be the server. But nothing stops you from having the application listen on both sides, so that both act as server and client.

Comment: I havent thought about that, thank you.

Comment: You are aware that sockets are bi-directional? The shown code `read()`s from the socket. There's nothing stopping the server from `write()`ing back to the same socket, and the client can `read()` from its side of the socket.

Comment: Also be aware that TCP is stream not message oriented. That means even if you send a 100 byte message you might receive it as 2 50 byte messages or 100 1 byte messages. You will not see this effect when the client and server are on the same machine (usually) but across a real network you will see it for sure. You have to keep looping on your receive till you have the whole message

Comment: you can send UDP packets without having to open aa connection, but the client still has to be listening for them